# How to load two navigation property in a single statement in order to avoid database round trips(if any)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

What i want is to load two navigation property in my class through database context using entity framework...the way I can do it with Include method...
And does it incur me two round trips or not to the db...

> Note: I dont want to load it with with EF Context's Include method

Currently I'm doing it this way

```
db.Entry(category).Reference(p => p.Section).Load(); 
db.Entry(category).Collection("SubCategories").Load();
```

I want to load this in one statement

Comment: Using `Include` method is the only way to load related entities in one round trip.

Comment: *I don't want to load it with with EF Context's Include method* Why not?

Comment: Because I can't use that in my case @GertArnold

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one trip using EF.  Try something like this (making some assumptions on your data/object model):

```
db.Categories
  .Where(x=> x.ID == category.ID)
  .Select(x=> new {
    Category = x,
    Section = db.Sections.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID == x.SectionID),
    SubCategories = db.Categories.Where(y=> y.ParentCategoryID == x.ID)
  }).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will give you one object back (in one trip to the database) that has properties hydrated for the Category, Section, and SubCategories.